# Configure a simple Google Search in External Data Source

Tags: lightning-connect, google, salesforce-connect

I want to configure Google search in my Org, so that when user searches something in the global search, results are returned from Google as well. I can do this using visualforce page. But i am wondering if 'External Data Source' could be used.

Currently, i have 'Salesforce Connect : OData2.0' and '4.0', 'Outgoing Email', 'Recommendation', 'Salesforce Connect : Cross Org' and 'Simple Url' as options while using External Data Source.

Thanks,
Mavsav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can creating a custom apex extension. You can then develop the extension to talk to Google via rest etc. I did a talk at Dreamforce about it: http://www.radnip.com/the-mystery-of-salesforce-connect-custom-apex-extensions-and-the-missing-video/